# What Linux distro would you recommend for a big all-purpose LiveUSB?

Tags: linux, distributions, live-usb

I am about to buy a 2TB hard drive to have all my scrap in one place. I will split it to some partitions one to store my data, and others to store OS distros and bootable OSes like WinPE and Linux.

I'd like the Linux system to be a fully-equipped all-purpose graphical environment (preferably with XFCE, but this doesn't really matter) with all hardware (including 3D graphics) automatic support on virtually any machine and automatic RW mounting of all available partitions (incl. those on this HDD and on a host machine (incl. NTFS, LVM, and FreeBSD partitions)). I'd like as fresh software versions as possible.

Should I use Mandriva Move, Knoppix, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I happen to like Mint as a base for a LiveUSB along with changes that I applied to the iso using Remastersys.  This allows me to add additional packages along with patching the system to have all the latest fixes.  I tend to remaster the iso every couple of weeks so I have a very up to date version that I keep with me.  This is very useful so I can visit other people and boot off my image without needing to trust that their computer is free of viruses and spyware.

http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a new version of Unity Linux that can be used to create a live USB from a HD install. Just tune the HD install the way you want it and then install to live USB.

> The 2010.2 release provides many
>   updates to core packages, much more
>   stability, refinements to the core
>   tools of the project like mklivecd and
>   unity-installer.
>
> Since our 2010.1 Final Release the
>   changes include:
>
> ```
> * Updated toolchain, openssl, xorg, python, mono, smart, drak tools,
> ```
>
> kernel 2.6.35.7, repository
>   restructuring and snapshot of the 2010
>   repository.
>       * Addition of more than 2000 packages to bring the total to over
>   10,600 packages per architecture.
>       * XFCE 4.6.2, KDE 4.5.1 (but 4.5.3 can be found in the Synergy
>   repository), Gnome 2.32.0, Openbox
>   3.4.11.2, E17 0.16.999.52995 and EFL beta libraries as well as several
>   proprietary video drivers for Nvidia
>   and ATI.
>
> Our work for the past 5 months has
>   been concentrated on making branding
>   easier, adding functionality to the
>   unity-installer to allow installation
>   of a livecd with a command line
>   interface, the release of mklivecd
>   0.8.0. Also be sure to note several new howtos over in the wiki
>   (http://docs.unity-linux.org/Category:HowTos)
>
> As mentioned above, the main branching
>   tool, mklivecd, got a lot of
>   attention:
>
> ```
> * Major code clean up
> * Support for plymouth (optional)
> * Added switch for no splash
> * i18n support
> * A redesigned mkremaster interface which allows to:
>
>     * Remaster your current live/installed system and make an ISO
> ```
>
> out of it
>           * Build an ISO from scratch using selected rpms
>           * Create a live USB starting from any ISO or LiveCD
>
> Another very notable mention is the
>   possibility to use unity-installer via
>   the command line interface without
>   Xorg running. This refinement allows
>   the livecd to be installed with as
>   little as 64MB of RAM.